# Why $\sqrt{(XY-1)} = (XY-1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Form Algebraic Geometry by Smith, in introducing Lauren's polynomials stated without proof $\sqrt{(XY-1)} = (XY-1)$.

I have difficulty understanding $\sqrt{(XY-1)} = (XY-1)$. It looks like $f(x,y)^n = g(x,y) (xy-1) $ never can imply $f(x,y) = h(x,y) (xy-1)$?

Comment: It suffices to show $k[X,Y]/(XY-1)\cong k[X,X^{-1}]$ has no nilpotent elements, which follows from the fact that $k[X,X^{-1}]$ is a subring of the quotient field of 
$k[X]$, which is an integral domain.

Alternatively, if $xy-1\mid f(x,y)^n$, then because $k[x,y]$ is a UFD and $xy-1$ is prime, $xy-1\mid f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Mastrem you should write that up as an answer. I'd upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

First, $f(x,y)^n=g(x,y)(xy-1)$ does imply $f(x,y)=h(x,y)(xy-1)$. After all $xy-1\in k[x,y]$ is prime. In general, prime ideals are always radical.

Another way to go: it suffices to show $k[x,y]/(xy-1)\cong k[x,x^{-1}]$ has no nilpotent elements. This follows from the fact that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is a subring of the quotient field of $k[x]$, which is an integral domain.